# In PyCharm I can run the configuration of the project but can't debug the project

Tags: python-3.x, django, debugging, pycharm

I'm getting trouble with debugging a Django 4.0 application with Pycharm 2021.2 (Professiontal Edition).

I have configured the Run/Debug Configurations with the right Python Interpreter. It's the basic configurations.

Running with Shift + F10 runs the project, but debugging (Shift + F9) gives the error message:

```
Connected to pydev debugger (build 212.4746.96)
<dir>/env/bin/python /opt/pycharm-2021.2/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py --multiproc --qt-support=auto --client 127.0.0.1 --port 46579 --file /home/caco/Workspace/CodeChallenges/desafio-dev-system/desafio-dev/manage.py runserver 8000
<dir>/env/bin/python: can't find '__main__' module in ''

Process finished with exit code 1
```

In other project the debugging mode is runnig accordingly.

I already destroyed .idea dir and closed and opened Pycharm again, but the problem persists.